# What security scripts/code do you add to your application.cfm?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, application.cfm

I am working on redoing our company's code, and I want to have a clear, easy to read, and reasonably secure application.cfm.

And no, we are not using application.cfc. So let's not discuss that please.

Just want to know what scripts you would add for security.

I am using coldfusion 8 standard, sql 2008.

Here is one of the scripts I am currently using, but I want to hear from some other coldfusion programmers.

```
<cfset temp = cleanScopes('form,url') />

<!--- another method to clean url/form data from http://www.garyrgilbert.com/tools/coldfusion/cleanScopes.cfm.txt --->
<cffunction name="cleanScopes" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="scopesToClean" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="charlist" type="string" required="no" default="">
    <cfscript>
        reTags ="<[^/>]*>|</.*>";
    </cfscript>
    <cfloop list="#scopestoClean#" index="scopeName">
    <cfif not findnocase("multipart/form-data",cgi.CONTENT_TYPE)>
        <cfscript>
            s=Evaluate(scopeName);
            for(field in s)
                if (isSimpleValue(s[field])){
                    if(reTags neq '')
                        do { prev=s[field];
                                s[field]=REReplaceNoCase(s[field],reTags,"","ALL");
                            } while (prev NEQ s[field]);
                        structUpdate(s,field,prev);
                        if (charlist neq '')
                            s[field] = replacelist(s[field],charlist,'');
                }
        </cfscript>
    </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn>
</cffunction>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am looking for scripts that will protect against sql injection, xss, crlf, etc.

Comment: Can you at least explain why you can't or won't use Application.cfc? You're coming off a bit hostile in that regard.

Comment: I am not trying to come off as hostile. It's just any time i specify that I can't use a specific method or technique, instead of people trying to help me in the way I do need it. They spend more time, explaining why I should use the way, I can not use. I apologize if I am rude. I just don't want to get into flame wars...i just want help in a specific way..sorry.

Comment: Fair enough, and I provided a thorough answer below. But for what it's worth, you still haven't indicated WHY you can't or won't use Application.cfc. ;)

Comment: I haven't seen a clear explanation of the differences and pro's and con's and certainly did not want to get into a discussion of this here.

Comment: And honestly sometimes you have no control of what you can do, just have to live within the technological understanding of those you work with and for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise against attempting to catch everything in a global fashion. There will inevitably be a few things that slip through the cracks, no matter how complex and convoluted your global protection code gets.

Instead, the "correct" (for what it's worth) method is to sanitize all content being presented on a page (or in an email, etc) -- during output -- that began its life as user input.

That said, take a look at [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). They have excellent libraries for protecting from all kinds of attacks, including the various ones you mention (sqli, xss, crlf). A coworker of mine recently wrapped up some of those libraries into a CFC that we can use in our applications, [and explained how to use it on our developers blog](http://beacon.wharton.upenn.edu/devcenter/2010/09/owasp-libraries-now-on-cf-8-servers/):

> ## AntiSamy
>
> If your application accepts user generated HTML, say blog comments for example, you need to make sure you sanitize your input to prevent XSS attacks. You wouldn’t want someone to be able to enter malicious code in your blog comments so you need some way to filter the input. Enter [AntiSamy](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_AntiSamy_Project). AntiSamy allows you to easily filter user generated HTML according to what it terms policies. AntiSamy is a Java project, so I have packaged it into a CFC for easy use from ColdFusion.
>
> The simplist way to use AntiSamy is to create an instance of the AntiSamy component (cfc.owasp.AntiSamy) and call the getCleanHTML() method on the input.
>
> ```
> <cfset antisamy = CreateObject("component","cfc.owasp.antisamy") />
> <cfset cleanHTML = antisamy.scan(form.someInput) />
> ```
>
> This will run AntiSamy with the default (fairly permissive) policy file and return the clean HTML markup.
>
> ## ESAPI Encoder
>
> The next library I’ve brought over from the OWASP project is the [ESAPI Encoder](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/1.4.4/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.html). Again this is a Java project which I have wrapped in a CFC for easier use. The encoder provides several methods for encoding beyond those included with ColdFusion. Some of the more useful methods include encodeForJavaScript(), encodeForHTMLAttribute(), and encodeForCSS(). Using the component is pretty straight forward, just instantiate it and call the appropriate method.
>
> ```
> <cfset encoder = CreateObject("component","cfc.owasp.Encoder") />
> <cfset html = encoder.encodeForHTML("<body onload=""alert('XSS')"">Test</body>") />
> ```
>
> One very useful method this library provides is the canonicalize method. The [documentation from the beta version of the ESAPI Encoder](http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/2.0-rc7/apidocs/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.html#canonicalize%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) gives a good description of what this method does.

However, if you insist on a global solution, why reinvent the wheel? Why not try out something like [FuseGuard](http://foundeo.com/security/). The price is probably less than the cost of the development-hours that would be spent cobbling together, debugging, and dealing with security problems that break through your home-grown system.

Comment: They'd rather spend the time on me, as long as it's minimal than spend the money on some tool. We're rather budget limited. We either do it ourself in limited time/money or not at all.

Comment: Well in that case, I would make use of OWASP libraries and identify where any user-submitted content (or tamperable - like URL variables, cookies, etc) is displayed and add proper encoding of the values.

Comment: How do you make a cfc Instance of AntiSamy? I know how to call/create cfc's, but what do I download to my server, to use antisamy?

Comment: You'll have to download the OWASP java libraries and then invoke them from a custom cfc, using `createObject("java", "...")`. I'll see if my coworker has any interest in open-sourcing his cfc wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'm not really sure this "global" approach is the best. I check **all** incoming data in **all models** that accept external data, with specific validation rules for each situation. So additional layer looks overkill.

Such scripts wont protect you from putting string into the numeric id passed into the URL -- you have to check it any way. You have to use HTMLEditFormat/XMLFormat in the views any way, and so on.

P.S. List loop for CFScript:

```
for (i=1; i LTE ListLen(scopestoClean); i++) {
    scopeName = ListGetAt(scopestoClean,i);
    //... following code
}
```

Comment: This is just 1 of the scripts I plan to use, what other scripts or alternative scripts would you recommend?

Comment: I can not recommend any "script" because data validation must be integral part of the application, I just include it as part of scripts that process external data (forms, url attributes etc).

Comment: It's not overkill, it's a principle called Defense in Depth.  http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Defense_in_depth

Comment: @Jason Yes, but using this principle can easily lead to the overkill.

Comment: I'm sorry, but using a global protection system (like a simple script or even a full blown WAF) in addition to properly coding your application is not overkill and there is nothing to suggest that following such a principle will "lead to overkill". Defense in depth will help to protect our applications when one system fails. Sure, you could go and Reductio Ad Absurdum and say that we could add a hundred layers and that that would be overkill, but no one has suggested that. YOU however stated that these two layers were overkill, and that is just plain wrong.

Comment: You can try to interpret other people words as you wish, sir -- this is your right. while I agree with you on the described defence practice, I can't agree with your accusal on the "overkill" statement because all I said is that I do not consider global approach "best" (which means "only" for many people) solution and added that I can't recommend any scripts. And this is not because I don't want to, as you may think, I just don't know any well enough to recommend.